# Is it possible to set UserControl always topmost over the app?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making FeedBack option in my WPF app. The main window has TabControl and statusbar below. Statusbar has a button, which shows FeedBackView with animation.

So, FeedBackView is not a window, it's a UserControl, which contains in Canvas Border.

The app has some options, which open other modal windows, so in that moment FeedBack form is inaccesible. I've tried to set Panel.ZIndex = 1 and that didn't help. So is there any way to set the form super topmost within the app?

```
<UserControl x:Class="UPR.Wpf.App.Views.StatusBarContentView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:v="clr-namespace:UPR.Wpf.App.Views.FeedBack"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:UPR.Wpf.App"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">

    <UserControl.Resources>        
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../../Styles/Buttons.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="xBooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Canvas>
        <Button Name="FeedBackButton"                
                Click="FeedBackButton_Click"                    
                Loaded="FeedBackButton_Loaded"
                BorderThickness="0.5"
                BorderBrush="Gray"
                Foreground="White"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                FontSize="15"
                Height="32"
                Canvas.Bottom="-17"
                Canvas.Right="-150">
        </Button>
        <Border BorderBrush="Gray"
                Panel.ZIndex="1"
                BorderThickness="2"
                Name="border" 
                Margin="-350,0,-178,-9" 
                Background="White"
                Canvas.Bottom="24"
                Canvas.Right="-5"
                SizeChanged="border_SizeChanged">
            <v:FeedBackView/>
        </Border>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: "So, FeedBackView is not a window" Why is is not a window then?

Comment: Do I understand correct that you want Feedback to be clickable while showing modal windows? I think you will need to add the feedback usercontrol to the modal form to be allow clicking from there...

Comment: Yes, I mean that. So is your variant is the only way? @Schwarzie

Comment: It's just the nature of Modal windows to block all UI interaction with other windows.

Comment: I've thought a bit about alternative, but they get hacky very quickly.

Comment: OK, thanks, will try to make it as  a window. @Schwarzie2478

Comment: Agree with @Schwarzie2478, instead of making it a window, just add the same control to all modal windows you have. This way you would be able to _also/easier_ trace the feedback context, because it'd come from a specific window. Or, well, do not use modal dialogs. I think in WinForms you could do Show() + AddOwnedForm() but AFAIK there's no such native API in WPF.

Comment: Couldn't you put your usercontrol in a popup if you didn't want it inside the modal window. I think you'd have to pop it up from the modal window if the user needs to interact with it.